# Drupal 7 Taxonomy term display page

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to display my content in Alphabetical group for a specific content type.

What I did?

> ```
> 1. Added a vocabulary "Category"
> 2. Added a term(Myterm) inside this vocabulary.
> 3. Added a field in content type and put the relation with this vocabulary and the default option is the term name.
> ```

This is working fine. Now I want to show up the Myterm page the content alphabetical group. For your information I used Pathauto module to create the taxonomy term url. So my current url is domainname.com/MyTerm

This page showing the results which are belongs to MyTerm term. I want to just display the Alphabetical group and each group will contain the content whose title starting with this group. Please guys advice me how to implement this. Thanks in advance.

e.g.
Suppose my requirement is like below:

[A]
Amazing Video
A good tutorial
Award wining software

[B]
British Council
Be right back

[C]
Case discussion
Content privacy
....

Answer (score 0):

There is a default views with name **Glossary** (admin/structure/views/view/glossary). Look at the **Contextual filters** of this views for how to create a glossary.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback or upvote it.